Torsocks --address ca only be IP but not a hostname?
I noticed if I make wget requests over torsocks and I specify --address, this only works if the address is an actual IP but NOT a hostname, is this correct ?
So this works:
torsocks --address 123.123.123.123 --port 9050 wget https://www.example.com/index.html;

but this with a hostname as --address doesn't work:
torsocks --address some.tor.proxy.tld --port 9050 wget https://www.example.com/index.html;

One of shown error is:
Config file unknown tor address: some.tor.proxy.tld

The torsocks --help just says:
-a, --address HOST Specify Tor address

If it only accepts ip but not hostname, maybe it was better to be mentioned there. Because seems kind of hard to identify this cause.
full error:
torsocks --address some.tor.proxy.tld --port 9050 wget https://www.example.com/index.html
1725663493 ERROR torsocks[32102]: Config file unknown tor address: some.tor.proxy.tld (in conf_file_set_tor_address() at config-file.c:281)
--2005-09-06 17:58:23--  https://www.example.com/index.html
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 1725663493 PERROR torsocks[32102]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
failed: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.example.com’


Do not abuse the way that Tor is built up! Use it as a SOCKS5S proxy, it will work fine. Mismanaging the logic of Tor leads to privacy leaks. In your particular case - just use it as a proxy

I don't understand where is the abuse there ?

Did you meant that it should only connect to TOR from same machine and not connect trough other tor gateways using --address ? From some locations I do not want to have TOR trafic, I can have these computers connect trough my TOR one.

I mean that the safest way to secure your machine(virtual or real) is to make it unaailable to leave the local network unless through Tor' s SOCKS5s proxy
